# How do I make someone walk in Skyrim?

Tags: scripting, modding, skyrim-modding

I'm coding a mod for Skyrim with Papyrus and the Creation Kit. I can't seem to get an Actor to move from point A to point B. I know there's a function to teleport an actor, but how can I make them walk or run using Papyrus?

Comment: Make sure you uncheck "arrow in knee" - it doesn't stop them, but it does slow them down ;)

Comment: http://www.creationkit.com/Bethesda_Tutorial_Packages

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the actor to wander around, give him a [sandbox package](http://www.creationkit.com/Sandbox_%28Procedure%29) such as `DefaultSandboxHomeowner`. This will cause the actor to mill about his or her home. If you have other packages assigned to the actor, you generally will want this sandbox package to be lower than them in the package stack so that it has the least priority.

If you want the actor instead to walk between specific points, give him or her a new package based on the [`Patrol` template](http://www.creationkit.com/Patrol_%28Procedure%29) or perhaps the [`Travel` one](http://www.creationkit.com/Travel_%28Procedure%29) instead. The former will require you associate a path with the package, so you'll want to have that set up first. The latter only requires a location but does not have facility for repetition, so the actor will move to the specified location and then stop.

You'd have to set up additional behavior to have the actor move *back* (you could probably do this in a quick-and-dirty fashion by giving the actor many travel packages, with schedule limitations that account for the time it should take the actor to make the trips, but at this point a patrol package would be cleaner... unless perhaps you need the actor to move across cells).